# Editing my i3 config file makes no change

Tags: i3-wm, configure, locally-integrated-menus

I am trying to replace Dmenu with Rofi but any alterations to my config file have zero effects. To start I used the setup wizard and ran:

```
mkdir ~/.i3
```

and then:

```
cp /etc/i3/config ~/.i3/config
```

After that I entered the config file at "~/.i3/comfig" and replaced the section on Dmenu with Rofi. After saving the file I did mod+d and Dmenu still opened. I edited the file again to have a different command in case it was a problem with Rofi but even still "mod+d" would open Dmenu. This is currently the edited section of my config file:

```
## start dmenu (a program launcher)
#Start rofi

bindsym Mod1+d exec rofi -show run

#bindsym Mod1+d exec dmenu_run
# There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
# shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
# installed.
# bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop
ere
```

Even after retarting there was no effect. If anyone has any idea what could be causing this I would love to hear. Thank you.

Comment: You need to reload i3, or log out then back in for changes in the config file to take effect. Your question explicitly suggests you did not do that.

Comment: @vanadium I just tried logging in and out again but still no changes

Comment: Good, but make that very clear in your question: use "edit".